# memory efficiency in python

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

Suppose I have some large array: `data`. I need to perform different operations, let's say `f1,f2,f3`. Of the following, what would be the most memory-efficient way to do it, or does it even make any difference? assuming I don't need to see intermediate results.

1)

```
out = f3(f2(f1(data)))
```

2. 

```
out = f1(data)
out = f2(out)
out = f3(out)
```

3. 

```
out1 = f1(data)
out2 = f2(out1)
out = f3(out2)
```

I'd assume that way 3 is less memory-efficient, but what about 1 vs 2? also, in terms of speed, is there a difference among the 3 methods?

Comment: method 2 allows garbage collector to collect the old instances of `out`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In method 1 the input of f2 (aka output of f1) can also be thrown away as soon as f2 returns (same for f3).

Comment: true but I wouldn't rely on it. Better use method 2 with interleaved calls to `gc.collect()`

Comment: how do I do those calls to gc.collect(), do I use just run that after ```out=f1(data)```?